# Which object does `this` refer to inside an event handler?

Tags: c#

Does it refer to the object the handler it is defined in or the object than handle belongs to:

example:

```
class foo  
{
 Object a;
 public foo()
 {
  a.handle += function;    
 }

 void function()
 {    
   this;<--What does this "this" refer to foo or object a?
 }    
}
```

Comment: `this` always refers to the current class instance when used inside a class.

Comment: `The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class` From [this C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

Comment: I can only assume that you are coming from JavaScript background, see [this in JavaScript vs C#](http://coding.abel.nu/2013/02/this-in-javascript-vs-c/)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I disagree with the duplicate. It doesn't answer OP's question at all. No doubt it's a duplicate of an existing question, but not of this one.

Comment: `this` is not Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to foo.  In c# the `this` pointer always refers to the instance of the class containing the method

Answer (score 0):

In an event handler, you can cast the "Sender" object to the type you know the object to be, and then you can tell for sure which object you are handling the event for.